# How to automatically add number to text-name of cloned inputs

Tags: jquery, html

I got a problem, that I'm trying to resolve for few hours already...
I want to change name of my automatically cloned inputs.

This is my HTML code:

```
 <form id="dodawanie" action="" method="post">
     <div class="formularz">
         <fieldset>
             <input type="number" id="indeks" name="indeks" class="pozycja">Indeks
             <input type="text" id="tytul" name="tytul" class="pozycja">Tytuł
             <input type="text" id="opis" name="opis" class="pozycja">Opis
             <input type="text" id="gatunki" name="gatunki" class="pozycja">Gatunki
             <input type="text" id="tagi" name="tagi" class="pozycja">Tagi
             <input type="text" id="rok" name="rok" class="pozycja">Rok
             <input type="text" id="pv" name="pv" class="pozycja">PV
             <input type="text" id="obrazki" name="obrazki" class="pozycja">Obrazki
             <input type="text" id="odcinki" name="odcinki" class="pozycja">Odcinki
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="dodaj">
    <button type="button">+</button>
 </form>
```

And this is my jQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var count = 1;
    $("button").click(function(){
        var kopiuj = $(".formularz").first().clone(); 
        var current_name = $('[name]');
        current_name.each(function(){
            $currname = $(this).attr('name');
            $('input').each(function(){
                $(kopiuj).find('.pozycja').attr('name', ""+$currname+"["+count+"]");
            });
        });
        $(".formularz").last().after(kopiuj);
        count++;
    });
});
```

How to add number to `name` attribute of cloned inputs?

Comment: Note that `<input>` can not have closing tag `</input>`, Instead you should be using `<label>`

Comment: Ah... yes. I always keep forgetting about that... Thank you for the remark, 
but that doesn't solve my problem :<

Comment: If you fixed the `<input>`s please edit your post to show the changes so we can put the code in CodePen, etc. There are other issues but there is no point in trying to fix it if we can't see the current, updated code.

Comment: Done, but it's not changing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is a bit overcomplicated, but seems to work (isn't it?). Check the simplified version below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        var formularz = $(".formularz");
        var kopiuj = formularz.first().clone();
        var liczba = formularz.length;
        kopiuj.find('.pozycja[name]').each(function(){
            $(this).attr('name', this.name + '[' + liczba + ']');
        });
        formularz.last().after(kopiuj);
    });
});
```

Try working demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/tvcsubaf/

Please note that it is probably not a good idea to send form data to your backend in that way. You rather should create array from cloned input values (ie. `indeks[]`) or name them according to scheme: `indeks-1`, `indeks-2`, etc.

---

If you decide to add `[0]` to base `name` attributes, and then increment this number in every next one set of fields, you can use below script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        var last = $(".formularz:last");
        last.clone().insertAfter(last).find('.pozycja[name]').each(function(){
            $(this).attr('name', this.name.replace(/(\d+)/, function(){
                return arguments[1]*1+1;
            }));
        });
    });
});
```

Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/9chwkx82/

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed.
If I do something like this: $(this).attr('name', this.name + '-' + liczba +''); (becouse without '' on the end, it's not working for some reason) its gonna be okay?

Comment: `$(this).attr('name', this.name + '-' + liczba);` - https://jsfiddle.net/m34scy8a/

Comment: I figured out, that I have to set name of default inputs to 'name[0]', to be able to put it all in Array and send it all at once to DB, how I'm supposed to do that?
I mean... how to change this: $(this).attr('name', this.name + '[' + liczba + ']'); to replace method, I guess?

Comment: Yes, you just need to replace number in string, using regular expression. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you again, could u take a look at my actual question?